# Industry Grade Selenium Webdrive Template

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've recently started learning about selenium WebDriver, and I've learned a lot of stuff from different sources but I don't have a good idea of how should a clean/professional grade script should look like and how should it's content be written.

This is an example of a login that I've created as a test, what could I change?

```
package Facebook;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Login {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    public void login() throws InterruptedException
    {
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement user = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
        user.sendKeys("user_test");
        password.sendKeys("password_test");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        user.clear();
        password.clear();

        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_u"));

        if(submit.isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("\u001B31;1m Succes");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\u001B31;2m Fail");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Login obj = new Login();
        obj.login();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks! I removed your question about printing text in different colors. That question has been answered before on this site and distracts from your main question about Selenium.

Answer (score 2):

You should spend some time learning about the Page Object Model. If you are going to build more than a few tests, it will be a significant boost to organization, keeping your code clean, and lessening the maintenance burden.

Avoid `Thread.sleep()` and implicit waits. Instead prefer `WebDriverWait`.

Don't write your own logging/reporting. Instead use JUnit or TestNG. They are well established and will save you a lot of time with not only logging but handling organization of your tests, executions, reporting, etc.

NOTE: Be careful about questions on SO that sound like asking for a code review. There's a whole other site for that, http://codereview.stackexchange.com.